# Linear Regression in Python: Scipy vs. Statsmodels - same R², different coefficients

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, regression, statsmodels

I'm running **linear regressions** with **statsmodels** and because I tend to distrust my results I also ran the same regression with **scipy**. The underlying dataset has about 80,000 observations. Unofrtunately, I cannot provide the data for you to reproduce the errors.

I run two rounds of regressions: first simple OLS, second simple OLS with standardized variables

Surprisingly, the **results differ a lot**. While R² and p-value seem to be the same, coefficients, intercept and standard error are all over the place. Interestingly, after standardizing the results align more. Now, there is only a slight difference in the constant, which I am happy to attribute to rounding issues.

The exact numbers can be found in the appended screenshots.

Any idea, **where these differences come from** and **why they disappear after standardizing**? What did I do wrong? Do I have to be extra worried, since I run most of my regressions with sklearn (only swapped to statsmodels since I needed some p-values) and even more differences may occur?

**Thanks for your help**! If you need any additional information, feel free to ask. Code and Screenshots are povided below.

My code in short looks like this:

```
# package import
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress
from scipy.stats.mstats import zscore
import statsmodels.api as sma
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# adding constant
train_IV_cons = sma.add_constant(train_IV)

# run regression
(coefficients, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr) = linregress(train_IV[:,0], train_DV)
print(coefficients, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr)
est = smf.OLS(train_DV, train_IV_cons[:,[0,1]])
model_results = est.fit()
print(model_results.summary())

# normalize variables
train_IV_norm = train_IV
train_IV_norm[:,0]=np.array(ss.zscore(train_IV_norm[:,0]))
train_IV_norm_cons = sma.add_constant(train_IV_norm)
# run regressions    
(coefficients, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr) = linregress(train_IV_norm[:,0], train_DV_norm)
print(coefficients, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr)
est = smf.OLS(train_DV_norm, train_IV_norm_cons[:,[0,1]])
model_results = est.fit()
print(model_results.summary())
```

**First regression (not standardized data):**
[image: First regression (not standardized data)]

**Second regression (standardized data):**
[image: Second regression (standardized data]

Comment: 1) You might not be able to provide the original data, but nobody cares about that; just use `np.random` to make arrays of the right shape which still show the behaviour you're puzzled by.  2) Please paste text, not images (values can't be copied out of images.)

Comment: (Oh, and for reproducibility, you can call np.random.seed first.)

Comment: Given that the only difference is in the algorithms that are used, the difference in result are most likely precision issues with floating point computation. Based on the kurtosis, there are most likely large outliers that cause large numerical noise in the computation.